# Visual Studio Converted Project User Control Designer File Incorrect

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have an ASP.Net project that I converted to C# from VB using InstantC#.  The conversion appears to have happened pretty well. Only a few items had to be fixed manually.  I did this after converting the project from VS2010 to VS2012.  Once I fixed the inferred method and object references, I was able to build once.

Upon viewing the page, I received an Object Null Reference Exception on an event handler assignment.

I built again.  This time, I received all kinds of errors from the methods and properties for code that referred to other user controls that the page has on it.  In looking at the designer file, it is not correctly determining and assigning the types to the controls.

I have tried manually changing the object types, but Visual Studio changes them back.

I have also tried deleting the designer file and choosing Convert to Web Application.

There are other user controls in the same project that work fine.  No issues.  Any other ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed this by creating a brand new user control, and then pasting the UI from the original user control.  Once I confirmed the designer file was generated correctly, I imported the code behind from the original user control.

To be sure everything went as planned, I renamed and excluded the original user control from the project and tested the new one. When I confirmed that things were working, I deleted the original.